# Merging 2 file vertically sorted

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

I want to merge two files of desired output.

File 1 example as below:

```
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
```

File 2 example as below:

```
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
```

The desired output is below:

```
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 1 2 3
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
VALUE 4 5 6
```

As you can see the only common is "LOCATION * " by which the rows needs to be vertically sorted.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk this does the job in my tests:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="LOCATION [0-9] X [0-9]"}NR==FNR{f1[RT]=$0;next} \
RT in f1{printf("%s%s%s", f1[RT],gensub("\n","",1,$0),RT)}' file1 file2
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file1
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1a 2 3
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 1d 2 3
VALUE 1e 2 3
VALUE 1f 2 3
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 1g 2 3
VALUE 1h 2 3
VALUE 1i 2 3

$ cat file2
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 4a 5 6
VALUE 4b 5 6
VALUE 4c 5 6
VALUE 4d 5 6
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 4e 5 6
VALUE 4f 5 6
VALUE 4g 5 6
VALUE 4h 5 6
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 4i 5 6
VALUE 4j 5 6
VALUE 4k 5 6
VALUE 4l 5 6

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="LOCATION [0-9] X [0-9]"}NR==FNR{f1[RT]=$0;next}RT in f1{printf("%s%s%s", f1[RT],gensub("\n","",1,$0),RT)}' file1 file2
LOCATION 0 X 0
VALUE 1a 2 3
VALUE 1b 2 3
VALUE 1c 2 3
VALUE 4a 5 6
VALUE 4b 5 6
VALUE 4c 5 6
VALUE 4d 5 6
LOCATION 1 X 0
VALUE 1d 2 3
VALUE 1e 2 3
VALUE 1f 2 3
VALUE 4e 5 6
VALUE 4f 5 6
VALUE 4g 5 6
VALUE 4h 5 6
LOCATION 2 X 0
VALUE 1g 2 3
VALUE 1h 2 3
VALUE 1i 2 3
VALUE 4i 5 6
VALUE 4j 5 6
VALUE 4k 5 6
VALUE 4l 5 6
```

Comment: @user222282 Did this solution worked for you like my tests?